# unable to send post request in dio - flutter

Tags: flutter, flask, post, dio

I'm trying to send Post request from Flutter(dio) to my Flask Restful API and I want to give the request body in form-data because an image file needs to be sent. The Flask app with the help of Postman - it works fine with my Postman's form-data, but when I tried with Flutter's dio package to Post the form-data to Flask gets an error in Flask.

The dio code is :

```dart
Future<List> apiRequest(int N ,File file) async {
  String url = "http://10.0.2.2:5000/";
  // HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
  Post _post = Post();
      
  var bytes = await file.readAsBytes();
  //TODO : dio post request
  var dio = new Dio();
  MultipartFile  multipartFile = new MultipartFile.fromBytes(bytes);
  FormData formData = new FormData();
  dio.options.headers = {"content-type" :"multipart/form-dataitem"};
  formData.fields.add(MapEntry("index" , N.toString()));
  formData.files.add(MapEntry("file",multipartFile));
  print(formData);
  await dio.post(url, data: formData,options: Options(
      method: 'POST',
      responseType: ResponseType.json // or ResponseType.JSON
  )).then((response){
    //response stuffs
  });
```

Postman request which works fine

[image: this image consists of my postman's Post request which works fine]

Flask statements that uses this form-data

```
fromJson = request.form['index']
Img = request.files['file']
```

The error in the Flask console

```
{exception: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.}
```

Comment: why is your `content-type` header value `multipart/form-dataitem`? is that happened during copy pasting code to so, or is it like that in the actual code?

Comment: yes, it is multipart/form-dataitem which is referred from postman's header which works fine on postman. it is written by me. I referred from others code.

Comment: is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown from the server because it's unable to identify the [MediaType](https://pub.dev/documentation/http_parser/latest/http_parser/MediaType/mimeType.html) of the MultipartFile. You need to declare the type and subtype for the the File that you're using on the HTTP Request.

```dart
MultipartFile multipartFile = MultipartFile.fromFile(
  file.path,
  filename: fileName,
  contentType: MediaType('type', 'subtype'), //important
),
```